# How to put HttpServlet and WebSocketServlet in same WAR file for Jetty 9?

Tags: servlets, jetty, war, jetty-9

Here is my custom `HttpServlet` implementation:

```
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>");
    }
}
```

And here is my custom `WebSocketServlet` implementation:

```
public class WsServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(MyListener.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.afarber.websockets.WsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.afarber.websockets.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is `$JETTY_BASE/webapps/admin.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Set name="contextPath">/admin</Set>
    <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base"/>/webapps/ws-servlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</Set>

</Configure>
```

Finally, here is `$JETTY_BASE/webapps/ws.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
        "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
    <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

        <Set name="contextPath">/ws</Set>
        <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base"/>/webapps/ws-servlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</Set>

    </Configure>
```

When I start standalone Jetty 9 (with `deploy` and other modules active), I get the error message:

```
2016-11-28 09:59:40.994:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.12.v20160915
2016-11-28 09:59:41.023:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///C:/Users/U299FAV/slova/jetty.base/webapps/] at interval 1
2016-11-28 09:59:41.152:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@783e6358{/words,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-11-28 09:59:41.165:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@7dc7cbad{/twentythirteen-child,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-11-28 09:59:41.950:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=307ms
2016-11-28 09:59:41.970:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /ws, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2016-11-28 09:59:41.992:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5f2108b5{/ws,file:///C:/Users/U299FAV/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ws-servlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_ws-any-239390
3927144372923.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/ws-servlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path: /: AdminServlet,WsServlet
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1504)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStart(ServletHandler.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:448)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:809)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

My question is please:

How to make `AdminServlet` and `WsServlet` co-exist in the same WAR-file?

When I comment one of the both, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the `doGet` method in your extended `WebSocketServlet`, it is just a normal `HttpServlet` with WebSocket Upgrade knowledge after all.

Here's a working example of this...

```java
package jetty.websocket;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;

public class MultiPurposeServletExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Server server = new Server(8080);

            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
            context.setContextPath("/");
            context.addServlet(MultiPurposeServlet.class, "/multi");

            server.setHandler(context);

            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @WebSocket
    public static class MultiPurposeSocket
    {
        @OnWebSocketMessage
        public void onMessage(Session session, String msg)
        {
            session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture("'" + msg + "' echo from " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    public static class MultiPurposeServlet extends WebSocketServlet
    {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory)
        {
            factory.register(MultiPurposeSocket.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello from " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

If you hit this with an HTTP request you get ...

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/multi
Hello from jetty.websocket.MultiPurposeServletExample$MultiPurposeServlet
```

If you connect to it from a websocket client and send a message you get ...

```
'Rock it with HTML5 WebSocket' echo from jetty.websocket.MultiPurposeServletExample$MultiPurposeSocket
```

Tip: use http://websocket.org/echo.html and use a "Location" of `ws://localhost:8080/multi` to test the websocket connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `servlet-mapping` part both your servlets map to the same URL. If so the container can't know which of the servlets it should route your request to for the given URL (in your case / - root).

Change the URL of `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to another URL of at least one of the servlets, for instance if you would change the latter to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

for example, your application should start up and both servlets are available but on different URLs.